# Incorrect Data in AP.NET TimeZoneInfo for Montevideo Standard Time

Tags: asp.net, windows, timezone, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 and this problem started at 4/Oct/2015.

Basically TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.UtcNow) returns True on the server for Montevideo Standard Time which is incorrect.
However when I run the same code on my local machine (Windows 10) it returns the correct value (False).

I know day light saving has been removed for Montevideo Standard Time this year. So looks like this changed has not been reflected on Windows Server 2008 R2 yet.

I have tried windows update on the server with no luck.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server needs the [August 2015 Cumulative Time Zone Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3077715), which includes this change.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I need.  Do you know why it hasn't made into the automatic update? It is a quite essential update IMO.

Comment: It has.  You must have updates disabled or something on your server.  If it hadn't, you wouldn't have it on your desktop either.

Comment: Strange. I couldn't find this specific update (KB3077715) on my server and  "check for update" shows the server is up to date.